# Visual Studio static library compiler hardcodes relative paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static-linking

I think my problem is that the Visual Studio static library linker hardcodes relative paths, and this causes problems later when linking against that static library from a different directory.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a library dll, call it base.dll.

I have an application that links against this dll: application.exe. In order to write unit tests for this application, I compile the application as a static library: application.lib.

I have a testing project that compiles testing.dll that links against application.lib.

In the last step, the linking fails with LNK1104 (cannot open file) because it is using the relative path of application.exe, not of testing.dll. Testing.dll has already linked successfully to base.dll earlier in the process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actual, complete error messages and paths for where all these files live might help get the question answered. Right now, I can't even tell which file the linker says it can't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to not link against base.dll when I build the static library, and only link against it when I build testing.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking "Inherit from parent or project defaults" in the "Library Directories" dialog for each project.

I have had similar issues with my own library projects, and there is not much documentation out there on this.